# Core data parent entity generated NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: ios, core-data

I have in my model a parent entity, "List" and a child entity (subentity) named "UserList" which is just a type of list. "UserList" has no attributes or relationships of its own, it inherits everything from List. List has a to-many relationship to ListItem.

I ask XCode 4.2 to generate the NSManagedObject subclasses.
For List it generates what I'd expect including,

```
- (void)insertObject:(NSManagedObject *)value inListItemsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)removeObjectFromListItemsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
...
```

However the generated "UserList" class does not declare any methods which would be ok if it was declared as a subclass of "List" but thats not what it generated.

```
@interface UserList : NSManagedObject
@end
```

Is UserList really a subclass of List? Can I just change the header? Or is something more complex going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things to check.  First, make sure you have given both List and UserList entities a class name, and then make sure UserList has declared List as its parent entity.

The generator is finicky.  If you have not specifically assigned a class name in the model GUI, it generates them on the fly.  Unfortunately, it means that, depending on the order in which they are generated, some may not be generated with the right information (imaging UserList being generated first... if you did not specifically give List a class name, it only knows to use NSManagedObject).

By convention, I always specifically assign class names in the model GUI.  I've not seen this happen when I specifically assign a class to each entity (under where you give the entity its name), but I guess it may happen.

Try to re-generate the class files.  It may just get generated correctly this time.

**EDIT**

Clarification after comment...

NOTE: Unfortunately, Xcode is being very consistent in this matter.  If you do not explicitly give class names to entities, others that reference it will be generated with "wrong" class names.

I suggest following one of following options for your work flow.

1. Always assign class names in the GUI for each entity.
2. Always generate the classes twice when you generate for the first time.
3. Use mogenerator https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator#readme instead of the Xcode class generator.

Comment: Whoa. It worked. I didn't change anything, just re-generated UserList as your suggested. The only thing that changed is that it now declares UserList as a subclass of List. I wish XCode wasn't so inconsistent. Thanks.